# react datepicker handle empty date and time value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

i have datepicker with time component in react which can have empty or null value date.

```
 <DatePicker selected={fromDttm} timeInputLabel="Time:" name="from_dttm" id="from_dttm" className="form-control" onChange={date => setFromDtttm(date)} dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa" showTimeInput />
```

declaration

```
  const [fromDttm, setFromDtttm] = useState(new Date());
  const [toDttm, setToDttm] = useState(new Date());
```

This code works when there is valid date value, but i am getting error when there is no date value. this happen only i use time `showTimeInput` parameter. i have no issues when there is only date without time.

Getting below error.

```
   RangeError: Invalid time value
format
E:/fuel-man-workspace/fuelman-frontend/fuel-man-ui/node_modules/date-fns/esm/format/index.js:371
  368 | var originalDate = toDate(dirtyDate);
  369 | 
  370 | if (!isValid(originalDate)) {
> 371 |   throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
      | ^  372 | } // Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
  373 | // This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
  374 | // See an issue about UTC functions: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376
```

i dont know why the react datepicker is not accepting empty value for date field with time component. is there a way to handle this. i need to display empty input if there is no value for the `fromDTTM` variable.

Comment: I've created an example and didn't catch any error. https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-glade-ymeuu?file=/src/App.js . What is difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct just do a little bit change in the `onChange` function.

```
onChange={date => setFromDtttm(date || "")}

OR

onChange={date => setFromDtttm(date ? date : "")}
```